# select parent for the property 'of' in the postion widget jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to select parent for the property of in the position widget jquery UI.
i use the bellow code

```
jQuery("#modalLink4").position({
  my: "center",
  at: "center",
  of: jQuery("#modalLink4").parent()
});
```

but it doesn't work correctly and its have error.
I can I select parent an element for the position I?!

Comment: `it doesn't work correctly and its have error` - What error? What does not work?

Comment: actually, the error dose not appear ,and just it not positioned of parent that i selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `of` declaration needs to be string name not the jQuery object. Try this:

```
of: "#" + $("#modalLink4").parent().attr('id')
```

or (avoiding `$`)

```
of: "#" + jQuery("#modalLink4").parent().attr('id')
```

See here
https://api.jqueryui.com/position/